# Python Selenium click() method on web application

Tags: python, selenium, click

I am trying to write a program which will interact with a web application.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/')

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(\
    (By.ID, 'Login')))
element.click()

print("Found %s" % element)
print("locatione %s" % element.location)
```

By design it should've open the browser, wait for page to load and then find and click "Login" button. "Login" button is found, but it doesn't click on it. Location is obviously printing wrong coordinates too. What are possible reasons and solutions for this problem?

Comment: can you show the login html code?

Comment: If your element is hidden then this situation may occur. If your element is visible then you can use java script to move the element to center of the page by using `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)`

Comment: As you are saying "Location is obviously printing wrong coordinates too" better you use ScrollIntoView

Comment: There is a difference between the button element that shows up as a box with the word "Login" in the UI, vs the div element with the id "Login".  Perhaps that is why you believe the coordinates are wrong?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, it was very helpful, obviously I was using wrong locator to find the button I wanted to click.
As I see my knowledge for the project I want to finish are superficial. By now I am familiar with some python basics and read [Al Sweigart's "Automate the boring stuff with python"](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/) book. I am not familiar with HTML and CSS and currently planning to learn some basics of it. If anyone has any advice of topics I should've cover before starting to write automated bot  able to navigate web pages I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: @АндрійzOFsky, was my answer helpful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try locating the button with another logic. For example, via class:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('call-to-action')
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To `find` and **click** the  **`Login`** button you can use the following line of code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='standard call-to-action']"))).click()
```